# MySQL CSV-Import Can't match values of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, import

I get the following situation:
I imported a .csv into mysql via "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE".

Everything works fine, but one column is kinda broken.

It's filled with "category-names" like 'LFP-Graphic Art' and 'Papiere, Blöcke, Formulare'.

If I look for a entry in the table with a simple statement, I get zero findings:

```
SELECT * FROM t_category
WHERE category = 'LFP-Graphic Art';
```

If I just let it show everthing in the table, I can see that there are indeed entries with category 'LFP-Graphic Art'.
I also already looked for whitespaces, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

I guess something went wrong with the Import?
I formatted the .csv file in UTF8 without BOM.

Edit:
When I update the dataset and just delete a character, then the select-statement works fine.

Example line from the csv:

```
active;supplier;SUPPLIER_AID;categorie
1;kb;10101;FP-Graphic Art
```

And the MySQL-table:

**t_import**

```
name, type, collation
active, tinyint(4), latin1_general_ci
supplier, char(255), latin1_general_ci
SUPPLIER_AID, char(255), latin1_general_ci
category, varchar(255), utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: Can you show a line of csv with that string? Also, have you tried with category LIKE '%LFP-Graphic Art%'?

Comment: The like statement works. But I need the exact result to work with it further. A csv-line is very long with 130 columns.

Comment: Can I see a line of csv?

Comment: 1;kb;10101;LFP-Graphic Art - I did cut a lot between out. I also tried to encircle every string with ' " '

Comment: And the table structure for that column?

Comment: Is the category field at the end? Maybe you can copy a complete line and share it with http://www.codeshare.io

Comment: I am almost sure that you can fix it if you specify the 'line terminated by' statement . The field with issues is the last of the row, right? Try with a text editor to see if there are hidden chars in the file. They may be loaded in MySQL so that where doesn't work while like yes

Comment: I edited the structure into the question. Yes, the category is at the end. Let me look up the 'line terminated by'

Comment: Have a detailed look at the file with something like notepad ++ or another text editor with advanced features.

Comment: YES. It works. I'm unbelievable grateful. I tried to solve this thing for hours and hours...

Comment: Will move it to an answer so you can mark it solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check the 'line terminated by' statement.
Since the field with issues is the last one it is possible that you are loading incorrectly the carriage return char.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it works with a TRIM(). I think there is any hidden character.

```
SELECT * FROM t_category WHERE TRIM(category) = TRIM('LFP-Graphic Art');
```

Is there is a line end problem you can update the field.

```
-- with a \n line end (Unix)
UPDATE t_category SET category = TRIM(BOTH '\n' from category)
-- with a \n\r line end (Windows)
UPDATE t_category SET category = TRIM(BOTH '\n\r' from category)
```

When it is possible to load the data again, add the 'terminated by':

```
LOAD DATA .... LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
-- or
LOAD DATA .... LINES TERMINATED BY '\n\r'
```

Comment: One or more whitespaces in the string between the words?

Comment: One whitespace. I also tried updating the dataset and deleted the last character. After that the select works - I edit it in the question